# pass variables - values to my fancybox iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, fancybox

here is the problem :

i have a fancybox iframe, init this way :

```
$(".caller").fancybox({
    type : "iframe",
    closeBtn : true,
    iframe : {preload : false},
});
```

it calls a simple form like this :

```
<form ......>
    <label>Test : </label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="myInput" id="myInput" value=""/>
</form>
```

i try to set default values in my iframe when it pops, so i add this in init :

```
...
beforeShow : function(){
    $("#myInput").val("test value");
}
```

But it has no effect... :/

Comment: Why not set them in the html?

Comment: The iframe is in a different scope. Treat it as a completely separate browser window/page. Add your script to the iframes source.

Comment: by the looks of it, since preload is set to false, you're really not setting anything since its not preloaded

Comment: do you have a file containing your html-form? does this file get loaded just right after the fancybox opened?

Comment: Btw, where did you find `beforeShow()`? http://fancybox.net/api

Comment: even afterShow does not work... it works on other fancybox i use. @Johan because here it is a "insert" popup, later i'll have to do a "edit" popup, in which i will have to set values dynamically from the .caller ID value... and get values of the ID from my db with queries..., so i have to be able to make the link between the page calling the popup (in fact, the element calling) AND the popup (iframe) itself...

Comment: I see. But regardless, the method is not listed. Have you tried using `onStart()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

- **Option 1:** You pass the value via HTTP-GET param to the iframe and read it within the iframe.
- **Option 2:** On the other side you can use the [`postMessaging` API](http://www.w3.org/TR/webmessaging/) to communicate between both frames. The Cross-window messaging security model at this point is two-sided. This means the sender ensures that the receiving domain is `targetDomain`. And the receiver checks that the message came from proper `event.origin`.

Example sender:

```
<iframe src="http://a.JavaScript.info/files/tutorial/window/receive.html" id="iframe" style="height:60px"></iframe>

<form name="form">
  <input type="text" name="msg" value="Your message"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<script>

  var win = document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow

  document.forms.form.onsubmit = function() {
    win.postMessage(
      this.elements.msg.value,
      "http://a.JavaScript.info" 
    )
    return false
  }

</script>
```

Example receiver:

```
<div id="test">Send me a message!</div>
<script>
function listener(event){
  if ( event.origin !== "http://javascript.info" )
    return

  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "received: "+event.data
}

if (window.addEventListener){
  addEventListener("message", listener, false)
} else {
  attachEvent("onmessage", listener)
}
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

You could use something like that to remove the iframe after submitting.

index.html

```
<iframe id="frame" src="frame.html" id="iframe" style="height:60px"></iframe>
<script>

  function closeIframe(){
     $('#frame').remove;
  }

</script>
```

frame.html:

```
<form id="my-form" name="form">
  <input type="text" name="msg" value="Your message"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<script>
    $('#my-form').submit(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         $.ajax({
                 url: 'http://host.com/action/',
                 type: 'POST',
                 data: new FormData(this),
                 processData: false,
                 contentType: false
                }).success(function(){
                      parent.closeIframe();
                   });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, now i pass the value through GET... to the iframe. this is the easiest way i think... BUT when i submit the form on my iframe, i'd like to close automatically the iframe (container) and start a jquery function in the "caller" page...

Comment: You could define an function in the parent window which will be called from the script inside the script. You can use the `parent` object for this. Something like this `parent.closeIframe();`
For more information see [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.parent)

Comment: so you mean that, when i'm on the iframe (called element), if i call jquery elements like this $("#caller") it will get the concerned element ON the parent? even if the script is written into the "called" element? (idk if i'm clear... :P )

Comment: You define for example an `function closeIframe()` in your main window which contains the iframe. Inside the javascript of your iframe you call simply `parent.closeIframe()`.

Comment: you're awesome :) thanx, i have problems, when i submit my form through my iframe with action = the iframe itself, my inputs are all set ok, but the $_FILES is always empty... even if i set a file... can't upload any file with this iframe system... any idea?

Comment: Thanks :)! Maybe you remove the iframe too early. I have updated my second example. So you can see how I would handle this. All of the form data in my example is send via ajax. When it was successful the function `closeIframe()` of the parent window will be called.

Comment: I see, but, this way, with .ajax, it is ok with standard inputs BUT i cannot deal with $_FILES arrays... i have to submit the form normally, and, after submission and things done with PHP i have to "echo" some js to close the iframe and then update the "caller" page